# Regular expression to allow file with only .txt or no extension

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that should allow files only with `.txt` or with no extension.

For example: `c:\document\assignment\test.txt` or `c:\document\assignment\testing`

This is what I have thus far:

```
^[a-zA-Z]:(\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9\\p{Space}[\\p{Punct}&&[^\\Q\\/:*?\"<>|\\E]]\\(\\)]+[^\\.])+(?=(\\.txt|\\.TXT))(\\.txt|\\.TXT)$
```

The above is working only for the `.txt` but not for files with no extension.

Comment: If something has no extension how can you determine that it's a file? Will a directory _always_ end in a `\`?

Comment: What language or tool are using ?

Comment: In Windows, all files have extensions. A file without an extension is a directory. So what are you actually searching for?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Not necessarily. You can have files without extensions in Windows but if they are not associated with any application you won't be able to open them, at least not with the right program.

Comment: @Sniffer I don't think that's the case here, but yes.

Comment: Hello Sniffer, i am using java.  I will File class(Java) to determine if it is a file or directory.

Comment: So using Java you are getting a list of file names in a directory and you want to filter the list to keep files only with `.txt` or no extension ?

Comment: Yes, but the above is only allowing me to choose .txt files

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression requires the case-insensitive flag, and should work with most regex engine flavors.

```
^(?:[a-z]:|\\|\.{1,2})(?:\\[^<>:"/\\|?*.]+)+(?:\.txt)?$
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/k66bb7)

### Explanation

The regular expression produces a match by matching the following sub patterns.

- Start of the string
- Find the start of a path: either a drive letter, a back-slash for a unc name, or one or two periods for a relative path
- At least one path item that starts with a backslash and follows basic conventions from 
  [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#short_vs._long_names).
- Optionally ending in `.txt`
- End of the string.

You can simplify the expression if you don't need unc or relative paths by changing to first capture group to just `a-z`.  You can add more extensions by changing the last capture group.  For example, `(?:\.(txt|exe|com)?` would match `.txt`, `.exe`, or `.com`.

Comment: Hello Daniel,
Thank You for the quick reply.  But this above is not working.

Comment: The regular expression works (http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/k66bb7).  Why it doesn't work in your code I can't help with without seeing your code.  Did you use the case-insensitive flag?

Comment: String testing = "c:\\document\testing\\assignment\\testing.txt";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:[a-z]:|\\|\\.{1,2})(?:\\[^<>:/\\|?\\*.]+)+(?:\\.txt)?$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(testing);


        if(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println("Match found");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Could not find pattern");
        }

Comment: `"^(?:[a-z]:|\\\\|\\.{1,2})(?:\\\\[^<>:\"/\\\\|?*.]+)+(?:\\.txt)?$"`  This might not be exactly it, but the problem is the escaping.  Also, no need to escape `*`, `|` or any other regex special character but `]` when they are in a set.

Comment: Hello Daniel, yes it worked but i had to modify it a bit.  
But it is not allowing me to have a folder like new.folder(but windows does)

Comment: 1) How did you modify it?  It would be nice if somebody else came across this answer in the future that it was fully correct.  2) Obviously that wouldn't work given your requirements.  The only way it would would be to allow `new.folder\`  With an ending backslash indicating it was a folder.

Comment: Daniel,

The modified looks like this: ^(?i)[a-z]:(\\\\[^<>:\"/|?*.]+)+(?:\\.txt)?$